# Selective resume from dpms off - how can it be done?

Tags: power-management, events

After I've used `xset dpms force off` or `xset dpms force standby` to blank my screen, the monitor comes back on again if I touch the mouse.

I would really like to ignore mouse movements, and only switch the screen on again when any key is pressed.  Can anybody tell me how I can modify dpms to work like this?  Or what subsystem do I have to alter, to distinguish between mouse and keyboard events?

I don't mind changing source code and recompiling to get the action I'm looking for, but I don't yet know where to begin looking.  I'm asking for some signposting, to set me off in the right direction.

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, but I think the resume from power save is common to earlier Ubuntus too.

Comment: Please have a look here : https://superuser.com/a/304207/201468

Comment: Thanks, @pim, that post looks very promising.  I'll try out the suggestion.

Comment: @IanB: Could you please report back with your results? You're also welcome to post an answer based on or quoting the linked answer.